# Using LoadRunner web_custom_request to manipulate page elements

Tags: loadrunner

Recording a http-protocol vuser script on my Rich Internet Application (RIA) results in some CLICKs not being recorded.

As i.e. clicking an icon to open a hidden menu, choosing a radiobutton and clicking submit (not creating any http-traffic (request/response).

Is it possible to use web_custom_request to do this manipulation manually on the hidden menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No web_custom_request() is a protocol level option at a level just above that of Winsocket.   It's pretty much a raw HTTP request.   As such, the call leaves and then heads down the stack.   A GUI level operation would require a call up the stack, which is counter intuitive for client-server operations as calls generally are sideways or down the stack (OSI Model) and results returned up the stack.